# Powershell with Selenium: Select Dropdown item

Tags: powershell, selenium

I am using Powershell with Selenium and need to select an item from a drop down.
The page is https://app.beefy.finance/ .
I need to change "Vault Type" from "ALL" to "Single assets"

```html
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$URL = "https://app.beefy.finance/"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($URL)
#----- Wait statements here ------
$Select_Option = $browser.FindElementById("select-vault-type")

#At this stage I have tried the following commands but they all error out:
Set-SeSelectValue -By Value -value 'Single Assets' -Element $Select_Option
$Select_Option.SelectByValue('Single Assets')
$Select_Option.Text('Single Assets')
```

I have even tried using xpath but that fails as well

Comment: The issue is that the `select` element in this case it actually a `<ul>` and the options are `<li>` without a value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the drop down for the object to appear.
Then you can find it and click on it.
i used it's XPath:

```
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$URL = "https://app.beefy.finance/"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($URL)
#----- Wait statements here ------
$Select_Option = $browser.FindElementById("select-vault-type")
$Select_Option.Click()
$Select_Option.FindElementByXPath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/ul/li[2]').Click()
```